# How come pandas_datareader for google doesn't work?

Tags: google-finance, pandas-datareader

I tried to grab data from google finance by the following code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import datetime as dt
start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 1)

dt = wb.DataReader('FB', 'google', start, end)
dt.head()
```

and I got this.

[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 24697: invalid start byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDn0K.png)

But if I changed 'google' to ['yahoo'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXrjj.png) (by using yahoo finance instead), it works fine. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: I just tonight got a similar error but while providing a list of stocks in a script that worked up until today. Link below may have something to do with this change? https://github.com/rsvp/fecon235/issues/7#issuecomment-332572738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/424).

A quick fix is below, porting from the source, paring it down and making a few slight tweaks.

I believe the issue is with the body returned by `requests.get()` and reading of the resulting bytes.  (The traceback agrees with this.)  For instance, try `data = requests.get(url).content` (gets bytes); this will fail.  Below, `data = requests.get(url).text` works.

I really haven't tested this rigorously but the Google API does appear to be working okay.  For instance, the export link generated by `url` does work just fine at the moment.

```
import datetime
import requests
from io import StringIO
from pandas.io.common import urlencode
import pandas as pd

BASE = 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical'


def get_params(symbol, start, end):
    params = {
        'q': symbol,
        'startdate': start.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
        'enddate': end.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
        'output': "csv"
    }
    return params


def build_url(symbol, start, end):
    params = get_params(symbol, start, end)
    return BASE + '?' + urlencode(params)


start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
sym = 'SPY'
url = build_url(sym, start, end)

data = requests.get(url).text
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

print(data.head())
#               Open    High     Low   Close     Volume
# Date
# 2017-11-30  263.76  266.05  263.67  265.01  127894389
# 2017-11-29  263.02  263.63  262.20  262.71   77512102
# 2017-11-28  260.76  262.90  260.66  262.87   98971719
# 2017-11-27  260.41  260.75  260.00  260.23   52274922
# 2017-11-24  260.32  260.48  260.16  260.36   27856514
```

Edit: The issue should be fixed on version 0.6.0 of pandas_datareader. If not, please reopen it [as bashtage requested](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/424#issuecomment-358801457).

Comment: ...I'll put it in a new question.

Answer (score -2):

from pandas_datareader import data
goog = data.DataReader('GOOG', start='2004',nd='2016',
data_source='google')   # Use yahoo and get answer
goog.head()`enter code here`