# Pandas DataReader work-around for Google finance

Tags: pandas, google-finance, quandl, pandas-datareader

I pull historical data for a large universe of stocks and ETFs daily. Quandl has pretty good free coverage of US Equities, but they do not have historical data for ETFs so I use the Google API as a backup for Quandl.

The recent Google finance "renovation" hasn't left me with a great alternative, so I am trying to apply Brad Solomon's work (thanks Brad, link below) to a **list** of symbols. Assume it is unlikely without a loop given that he is creating URLs. Any clever ideas welcome.

Related question: [How come pandas_datareader for google doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561211/how-come-pandas-datareader-for-google-doesnt-work/47596588#47596588)

Thanks.

Comment: Github issue is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/424) if you'd like to track it.  I haven't ever contributed to the package but will try to make some pull requests this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, pandas-datareader is looping through each symbol that you pass and making http requests one by one.

Here's the function that does that in the base class, from which the google- and yahoo-related classes inherit: [`base._DailyBaseReader._dl_mult_symbols`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/base.py#L189).

The magic is that these are appended to a list and then aggregated into a pandas [`Panel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html).

I would note, however, that Panel is deprecated and you can get the same functionality in a DataFrame with a MultiIndex, a structure that's technically 2-dimenionsal but replicates higher dimensionalities in practice.

So, here's the barebones of what you could do, below.  **Please note I'm skipping a lot of the functionality embedded within the package itself**, such as [parsing string dates to datetime](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/_utils.py#L18).

```
import datetime
from io import StringIO

import requests
from pandas.io.common import urlencode
import pandas as pd

BASE = 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical'


def get_params(sym, start, end):
    params = {
        'q': sym,
        'startdate': start.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
        'enddate': end.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
        'output': "csv"
    }
    return params


def build_url(sym, start, end):
    params = get_params(sym, start, end)
    return BASE + '?' + urlencode(params)


def get_one_data(sym, start=None, end=None):
    if not start:
        start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    if not end:
        end = datetime.datetime.today()
    url = build_url(sym, start, end)
    data = requests.get(url).text
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col='Date',
                       parse_dates=True).sort_index()


def get_multiple(sym, start=None, end=None, return_type='Panel'):
    if isinstance(sym, str):
        return get_one_data(sym, start=start, end=end)
    elif isinstance(sym, (list, tuple, set)):
        res = {}
        for s in sym:
            res[s] = get_one_data(s, start, end)
        # The actual module also implements a 'passed' and 'failed'
        #     check here and also using chunking to get around
        #     data retreival limits (I believe)

    if return_type.lower() == 'panel':
        return pd.Panel(res).swapaxes('items', 'minor')
    elif return_type.lower() == 'mi':  # MultiIndex DataFrame
        return pd.concat((res), axis=1)
```

An example:

```
syms = ['AAPL', 'GE']
data = get_multiple(syms, return_type='mi')

# Here's how you would filter down to Close prices
#   on MultiIndex columns
data.xs('Close', axis=1, level=1) 

              AAPL     GE
Date                     
2010-01-04   30.57  15.45
2010-01-05   30.63  15.53
2010-01-06   30.14  15.45
2010-01-07   30.08  16.25
2010-01-08   30.28  16.60
...
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, good insight. Despite the imperfections, I have found panels to be faster than multiindexed dfs for large datasets. Hoping xarray matures quickly. Appreciate your time.